# Complete user guide to Xen 4.2

Tags: untagged

Is there a complete guide to Xen 4.2? So far I've tryed googling without success could anyone give some good reference preferably freely downloadable.

Comment: What did you type into Google that managed to produce *no* results?  I tried putting your question title in and the only results that were not the required user manual were the manuals for versions 4.0 and 3.0.

Comment: @Ladadadada this xen user guide v 4.2. The only Xen guide google posted to me where Xen v3.0.

Comment: to the people who closed thise question: https://candidcoma.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/congratulations-idiot.gif

Answer (score 5):

...did you look at the [Xen website](http://www.xen.org/support/documentation.html)? I'm not sure what you're looking for that wouldn't be covered there. Otherwise you can look for Xen books on Amazon, but the website may have a lot of material already, or newsgroups/mailing lists to interact with others; if you have a specific question you can post it here. Otherwise this is a wee bit vague as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: First of all, yes I've seen Xen website, but I've found the structures of the wiki fragmentary, in particular I can't find answers to many problems that I'm having. By the way I didn't thought that asking for a guide that someone had used to learn Xen was a so useless question. I apologize.

Comment: Well, I didn't vote you down, you were vague in what your actual root problem was, and your snarky reply is not properly formatted because your "first of all" implies a "second" which you didn't get to. If you're going to be sore about it then you're better off saying nothing or clarifying your question so you can get a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to ask a more specific question, I apologize for my bad english and my bad tone.

Comment: @Bart: the xen website docu is crap and all the books are dealing with Xen 3 and not 4. it may be that there are lot of simliarities but i dont wanna play that puzzel game to find out whats xen 3 and whats xen 4 specific. i want a xen 4 documentation that actually really works when used in practice.

Comment: @Chris I wouldn't hold out much hope on the project being of high quality if they themselves cannot provide decent documentation since I'd think they are in the best position to document their own project. The next best bet for the most up to date working information is to see if they have a specific mailing list you can subscribe to to get information.

Comment: I have no idea what the state of their documentation is; I submitted my answer nearly 2 years ago. Seems many businesses that need reliable support have moved to Hyper-V or pay-for services like VMware, or hiring people experienced in Xen configuration.